# undefined local variable or method `user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble with Devise/Omniauth with the error shown on the title. This is the line it points to:

```
 <%= link_to "Sign In With Facebook", user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Here are my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'pages#home'

  devise_for :users, 
    :path => '', 
    :path_names => {:sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout', :edit => 'profile'},
    :controllers => {:omniauth_callbacks => 'omniauth_callbacks'}

end
```

Relevant Rake Routes

```
user_omniauth_authorize GET|POST /auth/:provider(.:format)        
omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}

user_omniauth_callback GET|POST /auth/:action/callback(.:format)     
omniauth_callbacks#(?-mix:facebook)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)`?

Comment: that is odd, I used it previously and it didn't work now it does, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will do the job.

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
```

Comment: that is odd, I used it previously and it didn't work now it does, thanks